# Javascript, do something before leaving page

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload, eventtrigger

Because of the new GDPR law, when a user keep navigating on our website, that will means that he agreed to the cookies, and we need to record that.

So, I need to be able to do something before an user leave a page, following a link or validating a form. How can I do that ?

I tried using window.onbeforeunload, but this trigger a alert, asking the user if he really want to leave the website. I would have to do two action before leaving a page:

- Recoring the cookies
- Launch a trigger that is going to set the trackers

  ```
      window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
          // Record the cookie
          // Launch a trigger to add the trackers
          return true;
      };
  ```

Maybe I'm making a mistake, if anyone could give me a hand

Comment: Actually, as I mentionned, if the user keep on navigating on the website that means he accepted the use of the cookies.

Comment: I do both, the law say that it they keep on navigating they are accepting the cookie, and it is mentionned "By continuing your visit to this site, you accept the use of cookie" , they can still change the configuration if they want.

Comment: Note that you probably want the `visibilitychange` event, because `beforeunload` doesn't always fire, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event#usage_notes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> When this event returns (or sets the returnValue property to) a value other than null or undefined, the user is prompted to confirm the page unload.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

So you should not do a `return true;` at the end of this function.

Comment: Sweet, that work, I only have a slight problème now is in the function I dispatch a event, that is going to create my trackers, but it seems like the event is not handled the page is reloaded before.

Answer (score 0):

You can always call your function before leaving the page using window.onbeforeunload():

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  recordCookie(); //function call for recording cookies
  setTracker(); // function call for setting tracker
  return; // returning null
};
```

**Reason for the alert**, asking the user if he really want to leave the website due to returning value other than null or undefined from onbeforeunload ends up asking for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Another question, because I use a event to create my tracker, Is there some risk that the eventListener for my tracker, will not be executed before the page is reloaded ?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    document.dispatchEvent(new Event('tracker.launch'));
};
```

My eventListener

```
 document.addEventListener('tracker.launch', function() {
    <!-- Google Analytics -->
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){ i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
});
```